# Tango ROS Streamer failed to connect tango on Zenfone AR

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to display point cloud from Tango on Zenfone AR on rviz like [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/tango_ros_streamer/Visualisation). However, Tango ROS Streamer failed to connect tango. Tango ROS Streamer said "Cannot register onFrameAvailable callback when onImageAvailable already registered!".  Because of this error, no images are published. If you know, could you tell me how to fix this issue?

Tango ROS Streamer has permissions to Camera and Storage. I checked them from [Settings] -> [Apps] -> [Tango ROS Streamer] -> [Permissions]. Tango permits Tango ROS Streamer. I confirmed from [Settings] -> [Tango] -> [Permissions].

Tango_ROS_Streamer log is followings:

```
830  7743  7820 I Registrar: Response<Success, Registered [/android] as publisher of [/rosout], [http://YOSHI-ROBO:42295/]><br>
07-25 09:36:00.831  7743  7797 I DefaultPublisher: Publisher registered: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</android, http://192.168.179.2:43773/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>><br>
07-25 09:36:00.834  7743  7800 I Registrar: Registering subscriber: Subscriber<Topic<TopicIdentifier</tango/status>, TopicDescription<std_msgs/Int8, 27ffa0c9c4b8fb8492252bcad9e5c57b>>><br>
07-25 09:36:00.840  7743  7805 I Registrar: Registering publisher: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</android, http://192.168.179.2:43773/>, TopicIdentifier</android/imu>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</android/imu>, TopicDescription<sensor_msgs/Imu, 6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2>>>><br>
07-25 09:36:00.859  7743  7821 I Registrar: Response<Success, Subscribed to [/tango/status], [http://192.168.179.2:45921/]><br>
07-25 09:36:00.873  7743  7843 I Registrar: Response<Success, Registered [/android] as publisher of [/android/imu], []><br>
07-25 09:36:00.874  7743  7840 I DefaultPublisher: Publisher registered: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</android, http://192.168.179.2:43773/>, TopicIdentifier</android/imu>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</android/imu>, TopicDescription<sensor_msgs/Imu, 6a62c6daae103f4ff57a132d6f95cec2>>>><br>
07-25 09:36:00.982  7743  7843 I Registrar: MasterXmlRpcEndpoint URI: http://192.168.179.4:11311<br>
07-25 09:36:00.988  7743  7864 I Registrar: Registering publisher: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</tango, http://192.168.179.2:49584/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>><br>
07-25 09:36:00.992  7743  7743 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_setBinder(void*, void*): Passing back the binder on the client end...<br>
07-25 09:36:00.996  7743  7743 I RunningActivity: Version of Tango is ok.<br>
07-25 09:36:01.016  7743  7867 I Registrar: Response<Success, Registered [/tango] as publisher of [/rosout], [http://YOSHI-ROBO:42295/]><br>
07-25 09:36:01.017  7743  7865 I DefaultPublisher: Publisher registered: Publisher<PublisherDefinition<PublisherIdentifier<NodeIdentifier</tango, http://192.168.179.2:49584/>, TopicIdentifier</rosout>>, Topic<TopicIdentifier</rosout>, TopicDescription<rosgraph_msgs/Log, acffd30cd6b6de30f120938c17c593fb>>>><br>
07-25 09:36:01.018  7743  7875 I native  : jni.cc:62 No remapping to be done.<br>
07-25 09:36:01.050  7743  7859 E RunningActivity: Trying to connect to Tango, attempt 1<br>
07-25 09:36:01.205  7743  7875 I native  : jni.cc:91 Start loading nodelets.<br>
07-25 09:36:01.277  7743  7859 E RunningActivity: Trying to connect to Tango, attempt 2<br>
07-25 09:36:01.499  7743  7859 E RunningActivity: Trying to connect to Tango, attempt 3<br>
07-25 09:36:01.722  7743  7859 E RunningActivity: Trying to connect to Tango, attempt 4<br>
07-25 09:36:01.967  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Getting config...<br>
07-25 09:36:01.969  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: void* TangoService_getConfig(TangoConfigType): Done getting config.<br>
07-25 09:36:02.214  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable(uint32_t, const TangoCoordinateFramePair*, void (*)(void*, const TangoPoseData*), ...): Connecting callbacks...<br>
07-25 09:36:02.214  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable(uint32_t, const TangoCoordinateFramePair*, void (*)(void*, const TangoPoseData*), ...): Done connecting callbacks.<br>
07-25 09:36:02.215  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPoseAvailable(uint32_t, const TangoCoordinateFramePair*, void (*)(void*, const TangoPoseData*), ...): Totally done connecting pose callback.<br>
07-25 09:36:02.216  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable(void (*)(void*, const TangoPointCloud*), ...): Connecting callbacks...<br>
07-25 09:36:02.216  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnPointCloudAvailable(void (*)(void*, const TangoPointCloud*), ...): Done connecting callbacks.<br>
07-25 09:36:02.216  7743  7890 I tango_client_api: TangoErrorType TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable(TangoCameraId, void*, void (*)(void*, TangoCameraId, const TangoImageBuffer*)): Connecting callbacks...<br>
07-25 09:36:02.216  7743  7890 E tango_client_api: Cannot register onFrameAvailable callback when onImageAvailable already registered!<br>
07-25 09:36:02.216  7743  7890 E native  : tango_ros_node.cpp:615 TangoRosNode::TangoConnect(), TangoService_connectOnFrameAvailable TANGO_CAMERA_FISHEYE error: -2<br>
07-25 09:36:02.240  7743  7862 E RunningActivity: Error connecting to Tango: -2, message: <br>
07-25 09:36:02.435  7743  7875 I native  : jni.cc:97 Finished loading nodelets.<br>
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267284/tango-ros-streamer-failed-to-connect-tango-on-zenfone-ar/) by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 46 on 2017-07-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The latest Tango ROS Streamer app can connect to Tango successfully!
So I close this question.

---

Originally posted by [graziegrazie](https://answers.ros.org/users/28176/graziegrazie/) with karma: 46 on 2017-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0